# JQuery: Clicking a nested Img with a certain URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a div having a certain attribute contains many nested divs. One of them contains an image tag with a certain `src`. How do I access that? Following code is not working:

```
var tbox = $('div[role="user"]'); // These could be multiple

tbox.click(function(){
    $(this).find('img[src="path/to/img.png"]').click();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the ["ends-with" selector `$=`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) :

```
$(this).find('img[src$="path/to/img.png"]').click();
```

You can see an example of this demonstrated below :

```js
$(function(){
      $("#box").click(function(){
          debugger;
          $(this).find('a[href$="test"]').css('color','red');
      });
});
```

```css
#box{
  background: #ddd;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='box'>
    <a href='#test'>TEST</a>
    <a href='#test'>NOT TEST</a>
    <a href='#not'>TEST</a>
    <a href='#not'>NOT TEST</a>
</div>
```